# Outlier absences of monomials in a group of inversion partition polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, sequences-and-series

Revamped and updated on Sep 12, 2022:

Given the complex coefficients $a_n$ of some generic formal power, Taylor, Laurent or other series, say the ordinary generating functions (o.g.f.) $f(z) = z +a_1 z^2 +a_2 z^3 + \dotsb$ for illustrative purposes, the coefficients of the series $f^{(-1)}(z)$, i.e., the compositional inverses of $f(z)$, or the series $h^{-1}(z) = 1/h(z)$, i.e., the multiplicative inverse of $h(z) = f(z)/z$, the shifted reciprocal of $f(z)$, can be determined from various sets of partition polynomials.

Specifically, the coefficients of the o.g.f. for $f^{(-1)}(z)$ are determined by letting $u_0 =1$ and $u_n =a_{n+1}$ in the set of associahedra partition polynomials $[A]$ of [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437) whereas the coefficients of the exponential generating function (e.g.f.) for $f^{(-1)}(z)$ are determined by letting $u_0 =1$ and $u_n =(n+1)!a_{n+1}$ in the set of classic Lagrange inversion polynomials $[L]$ of [A134685](https://oeis.org/A134685).

Alternatively, one could obtain the coefficient polynomials $R_n(a_1,...,a_n)$ of the o.g.f. of the shifted reciprocal of $f(z)$ using the set of reciprocal polynomials $[R]$ of [A263633](https://oeis.org/A263633) ( refined Pascal polynomials) and then let $h_0 =1$ and $h_n = R_n$ in the set of refined Narayana polynomials $[N]$ of [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264), characterizing the combinatorics of noncrossing partitions, among other combinatorial constructs.

Denote the equivalence of the two methods of deriving the compositional inverse o.g.f. for an o.g.f. by

$$[A] = [N][R].$$

The equivalent e.g.f. relation is

$$[L] = [E][P],$$

where $[P]$ is the set of permutahedra polynomials of [A133314](https://oeis.org/A133314) giving the reciprocal e.g.f.s of e.g.f.s and $[E]$ is the set of refined Eulerian polynomials of [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271).

Since $[L]^2 = [A]^2 = [P]^2 = [R]^2 = [I]$, where $[I]$ is the substitutional identity, we also have the conjugate dual inverses

$$[N]^{-1}= [R][A] =[R][N][R]  $$

and

$$[E]^{-1}= [P][L] =[P][E][P] .$$

All these sets of partition polynomials share one common attribute--the lengths of the polynomials as measured by the number of distinct monomials in each polynomial are given by [A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041), enumerating the number of partitions of the integers $n= 1,2, 3, ...$. For example, inspect the refined Eulerian partition polynomial $E_4  =  a_1^4 + 11 a_1^2 a_2 + 4 a_2^2 + 7 a_1 a_3 + a_4$, given below. The partitions of the integer $4$ are $(1+1+1+1)$, $(1+1+2)$, $(2+2)$, $(1+3)$, $(4)$, or, as commonly denoted $[1]^4$, $[1]^2[2]$, $[2]^2$, $[1][3]$, $[4]$ or $1^4$, $1^22$, $2^2$, $1\;3$, $4$, which can be identified with the monomials $a_1^4$, $a_1^2a_2$, $a_2^2$, $a_1a_3$, $a_4$, respectively. This bijection of the partitions of the natural numbers (see Abramowitz and Stegun p. 831, link in A000041 for the partitions) with the monomials of the partition polynomials holds for all the sets of partition polynomials presented above as well as those related to the composition partition polynomials of [A036040](https://oeis.org/A036040), [A036039](https://oeis.org/A036039), and [A130561](https://oeis.org/A130561) and their inverses, w.r.t. the indeterminates, [A263916](https://oeis.org/A263916), [A127671](https://oeis.org/A127671), and [A263634](https://oeis.org/A263634). The lengths of the polynomials in all these sets of partition polynomials as measured by the number of monomials in a polynomial are given by A000041 $= (1,2,3,5,7,11,15,\dotsc)$.

However, conjugate duals to $[L]$ and $[A]$ break this pattern. These are $[RT]$, the reciprocal tangent polynomials (draft/A356144), which can be defined by the substitutional identity

$$[RT] = [P][L][P] = [P][E]$$

and $[K]$, the Schur self-convolution expansion coefficient polynomials of [A355201](https://oeis.org/A355201), which can be defined by

$$[K] = [R][A][R] = [R][N].$$

I understand the combinatorics of $[K]$ fairly well, so I can account for the lengths of these polynomials being, after the first two, one less than those of $[E]$. However, I have not been able to determine the lengths of $[RT]$, except for the first ten or so by inspection. The lengths do not vary systematically; for the first ten polynomials the lengths are given by A000041 except for $RT_7$ and $RT_8$ which are missing the partitions $a_2a_5$ and $a_1^3a_2a_3$, respectively. (Edit 9/17/22: Max Alexseyev has provided [SageMath code](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/64028/finding-absent-partitions-in-polynomials-using-sagemath/) and identified a missing $a_2 a_4 a_7$ in $RT_{13}$, $a_5 a_9$ in $RT_{14}$, and $a_9 a_{14}$ in $RT_{23}$. No others are missing up through $RT_{30}$.)

***Can anyone identify which monomials are missing in the set $[RT]$ or give the lengths of the polynomials in general?***

---

---

Another characterization of $[RT]$:

given the e.g.f.

$$f'(x) = 1 /[1 + a_1x + a_2 \frac{x^2}{2!} + a_3 \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots],$$

$$RT_n(a_1,...,a_2) = D^n_{x=0} \;\frac{1}{D_x f^{(-1)}(x)} =  D^n_{x=0} f'(f^{(-1)}(x))$$,

where $D_x =  \frac{d}{dx}$ and the primes denote differentiation w.r.t. the argument of a function.

---

---

A crude SageMath code for computing the first ten $RT_n$ for inspection:

```
B.<a1,a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
A.<x> = PowerSeriesRing(B)
f = 1/(1 + a1 x + a2 x^2/factorial(2) + a3 x^3/factorial(3) + a4 x^4/factorial(4) + a5 x^5/factorial(5) + a6 x^6/factorial(6) + a7 x^7/factorial(7) + a8 x^8/factorial(8) + a9 x^9/factorial(9) + a10 x^10/factorial(10) )
g = integrate(f)
h = g.reverse()
w = derivative(h,x)
I = 1 / w ; I
```

However, asterisks must be inserted for the multiplications in the definition for f, and a factorial normalization factor for I when examaning a specific polynomial needs to be inserted since the returned expression is an o.g.f. rather than an e.g.f..

---

---

The first few polynomials of $[RT]$, $[E]$, and $[P]$ and some general attributes of $RT_n$:

\begin{gather*}
[RT] \\
RT_0 =  1, \\
RT_1 = -a_1, \\
RT_2 = - a_2 + a_1^2, \\
RT_3 = -a_3  + 2 a_1 a_2 - a_1^3, \\
RT_4 = - a_4 + a_1 a_3 + 2 a_2^2 - 3 a_1^2 a_2 +  a_1^4, \\
RT_5 = - a_5 - a_1 a_4  + 5 a_2 a_3 - 2 a_1^2 a_3 - 4 a_1a_2^2 + 4 a_1^3a_2 - a_1^5, \\
RT_6 = - a_6 - 4 a_1 a_5 + 4 a_2 a_4 + 5 a_3^2 - 4 a_1^2 a_4 - 2  a_1 a_2 a_3 - 4 a_2^3 + 2 a_1^3 a_3 + 8 a_1^2 a_2^2 - 5 a_1^4 a_2 + a_1^6, \\
RT_7 = - a_7 - 8 a_1 a_6 + 0 a_2 a_5 + 14 a_3 a_4 - 16 a_1^2 a_5 + 2 a_1 a_2 a_4 + 13 a_1 a_3^2 - 14a_2^2 a_3 - 6 a_1^3 a_4 + 18 a_1^2 a_2a_3 + 8 a_1a_2^3 - 3 a_1^4 a_3 - 12 a_1^3 a_2^2 + 6 a_1^5 a_2 - a_1^7, \\
RT_8 =  a_1^8 - 7 a_1^6 a_2 + 18 a_1^4 a_2^2 + 3 a_1^5 a_3 - 20 a_1^2 a_2^3 + 0 a_1^3 a_2 a_3 - 15 a_1^4 a4 + 8 a_2^4 + 18 a_1 a_2^2 a_3 + 57 a_1^2 a_3^2 + 6 a_1^2 a_2 a_4 - 54 a_1^3 a_5 - 15 a_2 a_3^2 - 12 a_2^2 a_4 + 84 a_1 a_3 a_4 - 30 a_1 a_2 a_5 - 48 a_1^2 a_6 + 14 a_4^2 + 14 a_3 a_5 - 8 a_2 a_6 - 13 a_1 a_7 - a_8.
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
[E] \\
E_0 = 1, \\
E_1  = a_1, \\
E_2  =  (a_1^2 + a_2), \\
E_3  =  (a_1^3 + 4  a_1 a_2 +  a_3), \\
E_4  =  (a_1^4 + 11 a_1^2 a_2 + 4 a_2^2 + 7 a_1 a_3 + a_4), \\
E_5 = (a_1^5 + 26 a_1^3 a_2 + 34 a_1 a_2^2 + 32 a_1^2 a_3 +  15 a_2 a_3 + 11 a_1 a_4 + a_5), \\
E_6 = a_1^6 + 57 a_1^4 a_2 +  180 a_1^2 a_2^2 + 122 a_1^3 a_3 +  34 a_2^3 + 192 a_1 a_2 a_3 + 76 a_1^2 a_4 + 15 a_3^2 + 26 a_2 a_4 + 16 a_1 a_5 + a_6, \\
E_7 = 56 a_3 a_4 + a_7 + 42  a_2 a_5 + 22 a_6 a_1 + 294 a_2^2 a_3 + 156  a_5 a_1^2 + 474 a_2 a_4 a_1 + 267  a_3^2 a_1 + 426  a_4 a_1^3 + 496 a_2^3 a_1 + 1494 a_2 a_3 a_1^2 + 768  a_2^2 a_1^3 + 423 a_3 a_1^4 + 120 a_2 a_1^5 + a_1^7.
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
[P] \\
P_0 = 1, \\
P_1 =  - a_1, \\
P_2 =  2 a_1^2 - a_2, \\
P_3 = -6 a_1^3 + 6 a_2 a_1 - a_3, \\
P_4 =  24 a_1^4 - 36 a_2 a_1^2 + 8 a_3 a_1 + 6 a_2^2 - a_4, \\
P_5 = -120 a_1^5 + 240 a_2 a_1^3 - 60 a_3 a_1^2 -  90 a_2^2 a_1 + 10 a_4 a_1 + 20 a_2 a_3 - a_5, \\
P_6 =   720 a_1^6 - 1800 a_2 a_1^4 + 480 a_3 a_1^3 + 1080 a_2^2 a_1^2 - 90 a_4 a_1^2 - 360 a_2 a_3 a_1 + 12 a_5 a_1 - 90 a_2^3 + 20 a_3^2 + 30 a_2 a_4 - a_6, \\
P_ 7 = -5040 a_1^7 + 15120 a_2 a_1^5 - 4200 a_3 a_1^4 - 12600 a_2^2 a_1^3 + 840 a_4 a_1^3 + 5040 a_2 a_3 a_1^2 - 126 a_5 a_1^2 + 2520 a_2^3 a_1 - 420 a_3^2 a_1 - 630 a_2 a_4 a_1 + 14 a_6 a_1 - 630 a_2^2 a_3 + 70 a_3 a_4 + 42 a_2 a_5 - a_7.
\end{gather*}

With all $a_k = (-1)^k$, $RT_0 = RT_1 = 1$, otherwise $RT_n = 0$. This is determined with $f(x) = e^{x}-1$ and $f^{(-1)}(x) = \ln(1+x)$.

With all the indeterminates $a_k = 1$, $RT_0 = 1$, $RT_1 = -1$, otherwise $RT_n=0$. This is determined with $f(x) =1-e^{-x}$ and $f^{(-1)}(x) = -\ln(1-x)$.

With all $a_k = -1$, $RT_0 = 1$ and $RT_n = 2^{n-1}$ otherwise. This is determined with $f(x) = (x - \ln(2-e^x))/2$ and $f^{(-1)}(x) = x - \ln(\cosh(x))$. (Careful, these are not the row sums of the absolute values of the numerical coefficients, which for the example polynomials are 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 18, 40, 122.)

With $a_k = k! 2^k$, $RT_0 = 1$ and $RT_n = -2\;(2(n-1))! / (n-1)! = -2\; n! \; \mathit{Cat}_{n-1}$ otherwise, where $\mathit{Cat}_k$ are the Catalan numbers of [A000108](https://oeis.org/A263916). This is determined with $f(x) = x - x^2$ and $f^{(-1)}(x) = (1 - \sqrt{1-4x})/2$. Similar results apply to the Fuss–Catalan sequences with $f(x) = x - x^{m+1}$, $m >1$.

Comment: "Does anyone have any intuition for the occurrence of this anomaly?" I don't even really have an intuition for what this question means. Could you clarify? What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: I'm not clear on the difference between bracketed and unbracketed names of polynomials.  When you introduce the refined Narayana polynomials and the Schur-expansion-coefficient polynomials, you denote them by $N$ and $K$, but you then later refer to $[N]$ and $[K]$.  Are they meant to be the same?

Comment: @LSpice, the same, oversight corrected. (Different sets of notes diff notation.)

Comment: This would be an unsatisfying answer, but since the coefficients are positive and negative, does it need to be meaningful that they sometimes hit zero?  For instance, the sequence of coefficients of $a_1a_{n-1}$ in $[RT]$ begins $-1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -4, -8$.  For $a_2a_{n-2}$ it's $-1,2,2,5,4,0$.

Comment: @BrianHopkins, certainly that happens analytically for $[K]$, and, if I recall correctly, it amounts numerically to 1-1 = 0, but I can account for the necessity of this cancellation via the lack of a combinatorial construct for the relevant monomials that is available for the other monomials and provides their nonzero coefficients. Physicists were clever to turn 1-1=0 into the Pauli exclusion principle with the Slater determinant. Perhaps a clever researcher familiar with the surrounding analysis and algebra can come up with a reason for what obviously must be a numerical cancellation.

Comment: One possible avenue that might lead to such a clever combinatorial approach is through the Fuss-Catalan numbers, associated with a number of combinatorial models, and their relation to row sums of $[RT]$. (Unfortunately I inadvertently deleted my intermediate calculations and can't remember if the numerical cancellations for $a_2a_5$ was 45-45 or 42-42 with 42 a Catalan number and Douglas Adam's answer). The easy way out is to assume it's a semi-random cancellation of numbers, but someone with more powerful apps already set up than I have could look for a pattern in other polynomials.

Comment: @LSpice, could you revert that edit of "this MO-Q" back to the original. It's meant to be a low-profile allusion that might stimulate some thoughts among those with a deeper understanding of an amalgamation of algebraic geometry, combinatorics, and differential geometry than I have, but now it stands out too prominently even more so than if it were emphasized with all capital letters? (But, thanks for taking the time and effort for the edits.)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1100986), as always, I apologise for any unwelcome edit; you are always welcome to revert any edits yourself, but I am also happy to do it, and have [done so](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/428059/7).  (Also, just a note:  the reason that I went with `{align*}` over `{gather*}`, which I originally tried, was that your original formatting had everything left-aligned, so I thought that `{align*}` captured your intent better (while also making at least some of each equation fit my screen!).)

Comment: An illustration of the use of $[E[$ is in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426884/combinatorial-models-of-the-refined-inverse-eulerian-numbers

Comment: Apparently, quite a few users here--many who typically post very few questions relative to answers, suggesting their interests and, consequently, knowledge, are quite specialized--consider ignorance and obstructionism virtues. (This is an attribute I've noted among particular users over the last decade.)

Comment: @BrianHopkins, regarding your Aug. 7 comment, typically when trying to find indications of a combinatorial model/regularity for an irregular partition triangle, such as A036039 or A134264, I let all $a_n = t$ or one $a_m = t$ and the other unity. Another option is to look at $a_1^na_m$ for $m$ fixed and $n = 0,1,2,3,...$. Can you give me instances in the OEIS where looking at $a_1a_{n-1}$ or $a_2a_{n-2}$ in an irregular triangle indicates some combinatorial regularity?